# check disk space while copying in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, disk, gnu-parallel

I am copying files in parallel using GNU parallel as shown below and it works fine.

```
export COPY_PRI=/abc/pri
export COPY_SEC=/pqr/sec

export status_dir=$(mktemp -t -d transfer.XXXXXX)
cleanup() { rm -rf "$status_dir"; }
trap cleanup 0

copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  scp bullseye@"$MACHINE_ONE":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_210_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || { touch "$status_dir/local_down" && scp bullseye@"$MACHINE_TWO":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_210_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/pri_down" && scp bullseye@"$MACHINE_THREE":"$dir3"/process_"$el"_210_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/.; } || { touch "$status_dir/sec_down" && exit 1; }
}
export -f copy

parallel -j 3 copy {} $COPY_PRI ::: "${PRI_FILES[@]}" &
parallel -j 3 copy {} $COPY_SEC ::: "${SEC_FILES[@]}" &
wait
```

Now I want to check disk space before copying any new files. If disk has 20% space left, then only copy if it doesn't have 20% space left, then exit out of the shell script with an error message and non zero status code. So how can I check disk space after every scp copy and make sure it is not reaching the limits? I have to check `/abc` and `/pqr` disk. They are two different disk.

Comment: you have the two commands "df" and "du" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix)

Comment: yeah that I know but how do I check whether 20% space is left or not before copying anything everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run something like this in the copy function before calling `scp`:

```
df /abc /pqr | awk 'NR>1 {gsub(/%/,""); if ($5 > 80) {exit 1}}' || exit 1
```

Explained (as requested):

- `df /abc /pgr`: Get disk usage report for mounts `/abc` and `/pgr`
- `| awk`: pipe to `awk` interpreter, `awk` script follows

  - `NR>1 { ... }`: execute this block for row numbers > 1 (i.e. ignore header row)
  - `gsub(/%/,"")`: replace percent sign with nothing so that it does not ruin the numerical comparison
  - `if ($5 > 80) { ... }`: if fifth field (`$5`) on row is bigger than 80, execute this block of code
  - `exit 1`: exit `awk` with return value 1 to signal error
- `|| exit 1`: propagate the exit value of `awk` to the exit value of the script

Comment: Can you add some explanation for me so that I can understand this stuff and how it is working.